# Using Left Outer Join, prevent intersection column from appearing twice

Tags: sql, json, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have two relational tables (the reason i'm using foreign keys is because kv is a nested objected in my json data):

```
CREATE TABLE analytics(
e VARCHAR(50),
t VARCHAR(50),
kv_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
);
CREATE TABLE kv(
kv_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
url VARCHAR(100),
name VARCHAR(100),
referrer VARCHAR(100),
id VARCHAR(100),
sessionID VARCHAR(100),
quote BIGINT(20),
category VARCHAR(50),
hitCallback VARCHAR(50),
eventType VARCHAR(50)
)
```

I am currently using:

```
SELECT * FROM
Analytics
LEFT OUTER JOIN
Kv
ON
Analytics.kv_Id = KV.kv_id
```

to display this:
[image: H2 table]

I am trying to get kv_id column to only appear once but *would preferably not change the schema*. If it appears twice I'll have to parse it out in my ResultSet object using JDBC. If I can get rid of it on the query would be much simpler. I have tried specifying what column names I want by replacing the asterik with the desired columns but it returns a syntax error. I have tried just two consecutive select queries. I have also tried a union but it returns that columns count don't match (I guess union is to add rows not columns). I am hoping the answer to this question will save me bloat on the java side and possibly point out any possible  problems in my schema design. If this is bad design please point that out, this is my first time transferring JSON data between databases and web applications.

Edit: I am using an H2 Database which [supports](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html) *"Compatibility modes for IBM DB2, Apache Derby, HSQLDB, MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, and PostgreSQL"*

Comment: just list the columns you need in the `SELECT` instead of using `SELECT *`

Comment: Thanks! This is explained by @Isaiah3015 more explicitly

Comment: This is so basic, you need to read a published intro to SQL. (Many textbooks are free online.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to specify the column name once on your join like so:

```
SELECT a.*, k.column1, k.column2  FROM Analytics a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Kv k ON a.kv_Id = K.kv_id
```

This will bring all the columns from Analytics (a) and then you specify all columns from KV table without the KVID

Answer (score 4):

Many databases support the ANSI standard `USING` clause.  If yours is one of them, then you can simply do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Analytics a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Kv
     USING (kv_id);
```

Otherwise, you will have to list the columns you want explicitly.

Comment: That's new to me. So, when you use `USING`, the column appears only once in the results when you do  `SELECT *`?

Comment: @Lamak Yes. It's hard to get search hits on sql `using` since it's a common word but read re select/join syntax in quality documentation--eg MySQL, Oracle, Postgres. Under the standard, you can't even dot a `using` column.